# How do you perform a "uniform shear" transformation?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

I'm working on a problem that asks you to apply different transformations on 4 vertices (rectangle), such as rotation, reflection, scaling, etc.

However, the 3rd transformation in the list is to subject the vertices to, "a uniform shear by a factor of 3". That's all that's given, and there's no mention of whether this should be carried out parallel to the x-axis or the y-axis. 
I've gone through all my notes and searched online but can't find a concrete answer. Is a "uniform" shear a combination of a shear on the x and y axis, or is it something else entirely?

I understand how to transform the vertices when the the axis is stated, but this is catching me out.

Edit: [Added copy of question for clarity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Wet.jpg)

Comment: I guess a shear w.r.t $x$-axis is a transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (\alpha x,y)$, which corresponds to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @anderstood, is it usually taken for granted to work it with the x-axis formula if it's not implicitly stated?

Comment: Perhaps it's a shear parallel of $(1,1)$?

Comment: @finn No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be
$(x, y) \to (3x, y)$.